# Extra low performance in landscape orientation

Tags: android, react-native

I have custom list that automatically slides down with animation every n seconds. It's about 600 lines of code and i think it doesn't play any role so I won't paste it hear for now.

The trouble is that I have extra low JS fps (near 0 all time and near 2 while animation) and app crashes after 2-3 minutes work when app is in landscape mode but always have >30fps in portrait. The landscape mode is the same as portrait but with two sliders (I've tested with one and had 4fps and tested without animation with the same fps) and other measurements of items. After some time of work in landscape mode in console appear messages:

```
Invalid style with id `316`. Skipping ...
Warning: View: `ref` is not a prop. Trying to access it will result in `undefined` being returned. If you need to access the same value within the child component, you should pass it as a different prop. 
Warning: View: `key` is not a prop. Trying to access it will result in `undefined` being returned. If you need to access the same value within the child component, you should pass it as a different prop.
Warning: RCTView: `key` is not a prop. Trying to access it will result in `undefined` being returned. If you need to access the same value within the child component, you should pass it as a different prop.
```

Id with invalid style may change every app run.

What may it be?

UPD 
I have rewritten one of items in landscape layout and it works ok, not perfect but ok. New and old versions had only one difference, it's styles:

In old version was a lot of rewritten styles like this:

```
<View style={[someStyleClassForVerticalItem, {height: 120, width: 120}]}></View>
```

And in new all properties are inline:

```
<View style={{height: 120, width: 120, backgroundColor: '#000'}}></View>
```

My idea was that it's the reason but then I started old version and it works correct. OMG. I have tried old version more then 20 times and in each I had the same crashes and now it works.